# Rails s doesn't work anymore because of gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server, rubygems

Recently I've tried to implement cloudinary in my project in order to use responsive images. After a few tries, it still couldn't work so I decided to delete my branch and try another solution. Back on master, `rails s` doesn't work anymore and I get this error message:

```
rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.4.1 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
        71: from ./bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
        70: from ./bin/rails:3:in `load'
        69: from /Users/yannlauwers/code/sarnico/rails-calendar-matcher/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
        68: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        67: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        66: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        65: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
        64: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
        63: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
        62: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        61: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
        60: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
        59: from /Users/yannlauwers/code/sarnico/rails-calendar-matcher/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        58: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        57: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
        56: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
        55: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        54: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        53: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        52: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        51: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        50: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
        49: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
        48: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
        47: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        46: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        45: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        44: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
        43: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
        42: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
        41: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:51:in `start'
        40: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:89:in `log_to_stdout'
        39: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
        38: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:27:in `app'
        37: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
        36: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        35: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
        34: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
        33: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
        32: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
        31: from config.ru:5:in `block in <main>'
        30: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:49:in `require_relative'
        29: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        28: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
        27: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
        26: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        25: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        24: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        23: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        22: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        21: from /Users/yannlauwers/code/sarnico/rails-calendar-matcher/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
        20: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
        19: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
        18: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        17: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        16: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        15: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        14: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        13: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        12: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        11: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        10: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
         9: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
         8: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
         7: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
         6: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/railtie.rb:84:in `block in <class:Engine>'
         5: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker.rb:35:in `bootstrap'
         4: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/commands.rb:25:in `bootstrap'
         3: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/manifest.rb:18:in `refresh'
         2: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.2/lib/webpacker/manifest.rb:84:in `load'
         1: from /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse'
/Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse': 767: unexpected token at '' (JSON::ParserError)
```

I had to do "yarn install", did bundle install to get my gems back to date.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: this looks like the relevant line in that error message to me /Users/yannlauwers/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse': 767: unexpected token at '' (JSON::ParserError), I'd guess that there's some real error in your code that's cause the server to blow up

Comment: I couldn't find the solution so I decided to delete my project, go to github and install a new version of it. It worked fine!